# OS dev: triple fault when trying to enable paging

Tags: intel, paging, qemu, virtual-memory, osdev

I am building a simple OS for learning purposes and I am (currently; I followed different tutorials earlier and customized something by myself) following [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20160326061042/http://jamesmolloy.co.uk/tutorial_html/6.-Paging.html) tutorial for enabling paging. I'm using QEMU instead of Bochs as my emulator.

If I keep paging disabled everything works fine (even the very basic `kmalloc()` I implemented), but as soon as I set the `PG` bit in the `cr0` register (i.e. enable paging), everything crashes and QEMU reboots: I suspect that some of the structures (i.e. page directory, page tables, etc.) I have are not created or loaded properly, but I have no way of checking.

I've been trying to solve this problem since a while now, but haven't found a solution. Can anyone see where my mistake is?

Here you can find my complete code: https://github.com/davidedellagiustina/ScratchOS (commit `83b5c8c`). Paging code is located in `src/cpu/paging.*`.

**Edit:** Setting up a super-basic page directory following exactly [this](https://wiki.osdev.org/Setting_Up_Paging) tutorial results in working code. Basing on this simple example, I'm trying to build up the more complex structures (i.e. `page_t`, `page_table_t`, `page_directory_t`) in order to understand the mistake.

Comment: Do you really mean "didactic purposes" (with the intention of using the OS to teach other people), or do you actually mean "for my own learning only"?

Comment: @Brendan I meant for personal use only. Edited post.

Comment: Assuming your have set up a valid page directory/table, the most common cause of a triple fault (a reboot) just after writing to the CR3 register (or enabling via the CR0 register) is that the instruction just after the write is no longer paged where it physically resides.  For example, you have paged your kernel to be at 0xC0000000, yet the physical address of the offending instruction is still at the location it was before the paging enable.  You must have that particular code paged twice, once at the original location and once at the new location, removing the old location at a later time.

Comment: *using QEMU instead of Bochs*  Why?  BOCHS's built-in debugger knows about segmentation and x86 modes, so it's better for debugging early-init stuff than QEMU's GDB-remote with regular GDB.  I'd assume there's some way to have the built-in debugger catch a triple-fault and let you investigate.

Comment: @PeterCordes I'm using QEMU because earlier tutorials I followed used that. I didn't know about Bochs when I started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out I was missing all the flags in the page directory entries (and especially the read/write and the kernel mode ones), as I was putting there just the page table address. I will keep my repository public and I will continue the development from now on, in case anyone needs it in the future.

**Edit:** Also, I forgot to initialize all the pages (with address and presence bit) when I created a new page table.

Answer (score 3):

In general:

- pointers should be for virtual addresses only (and should never be used for physical addresses)
- physical addresses should probably be using a typedef (e.g. like `typedef uint32_t phys_address_t`) so that later (when you want to support PAE/Physical Address Extensions) you can change the type (e.g. use `typedef uint64_t phys_address_t` instead) without breaking everything. This also means you get compile-time warnings/errors when you make silly mistakes (e.g. using a virtual address/pointer where you need a physical address/unsigned integer).
- almost all of the kernel should be using pointers/virtual addresses for everything. Physical addresses are only used by some device drivers (for bus mastering/DMA) and for the physical memory management itself (to allocate physical pages for page tables, etc; before mapping them into a virtual address space). This includes high level memory management ("kmalloc()" should return a `void *` pointer and not a physical address).
- during boot, there's a small period of time when none of the kernel's normal code can work because it uses virtual addresses and paging hasn't been initialized yet. To minimize the size of this period of time (and code duplication caused by having 2 versions of functions - one for "before paging initialized" and another for "after paging initialized") you want to initialize paging as soon as possible; either with a dedicated piece of assembly language startup code that's executed before "main()" (possibly using "statically allocated at compile time" memory in the kernel's ".bss" section for the page directory and page tables), or in the boot loader itself (which is cleaner and more powerful/flexible). Things like setting up a valid kernel stack, and initializing  (physical, virtual then heap) memory management, can/should wait until after paging has been initialized.
- for identity mapping; you'd only need 2 loops (one to create page directory entries and another to create all page table entries), where both loops can be like this (just with different initial values in `eax`, `ecx` and `edi`):

  ```
  .nextEntry:
      stosd
      add eax,0x00001000
      loop .nextEntry
  ```
- identity mapping isn't great. Normally you want the kernel at a high virtual address (e.g. 0xC0000000) with an area of "deliberately not used to catch NULL pointers" at 0x0000000, and user-space (processes, etc) using normal virtual addresses between them (e.g. maybe starting at virtual address 0x00400000). This makes it annoying for the code that initializes paging and the kernel's linker script (which is why it's cleaner to initialize paging in the boot loader and avoid the mess in the kernel). For this case; you will need to temporarily identity map one page (the page containing the final "`mov cr0`" that enables paging and the `jmp kernel_entry` that transfers control to code/the kernel at a higher address), and will want to delete that temporarily identity mapped page after kernel's main is started.
- you will need to become "very familiar" with the debugging capabilities of your emulator. Qemu has a log that can provide very useful clues, and includes a built in monitor that offers a variety of commands (see https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/QEMU/Monitor ). You should be able to replace the "`mov cr0`" (that enables paging) with an endless loop (`.die: jmp die`), then use the monitor to stop the emulator after it reaches the endless loop and inspect everything (contents of `cr3`, contents of physical memory) and find out what is wrong with the page directory or page table entries (and do similar immediately after paging is enabled to inspect the virtual address space before your code does anything with it). Qemu also allows you to attach a remote debugger (GDB).